# Missing template for create. Internal Server Error - Polymer form save to DB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, post, polymer

I'm creating a form for data collection which I am trying to implement using Polymer.

I've tried implementing the submit by binding a button to some JQuery to submit the form and also using Rails' own submit form helper but to no avail. 
The error messages are pretty vague and haven't given me much insight into the problem.

From what I understand, the reason it is attempting to render a create.html.erb is because in the event that the action fails it will try to render a view with a name matching that action. I have also included redirect to the /new action in the event that the save to the DB in the create action fails however this doesn't appear to work.

I have also checked the structure of my parameters number of times and they appear to be in the correct format.

Can anyone see where it is going wrong here?

Server log:

```
Started POST "/monuments" for ::1 at 2016-04-18 15:16:06 +0100
Processing by MonumentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DKt++BX5141UhbH2jyNmUDXWj24PoPxa2UGVQFubTAxbjRPhhwTHvnAxtVQgdptM9jlu+0CKMX6HeUkCJo1saA==", 
   "monument"=>{"visit_date"=>"2016-04-18", 
   "site_name"=>"Site 1", 
   "parish"=>"Parish 1", 
   "designation_no"=>"1010101", 
   "her_no"=>"1100110", 
   "site_type"=>"Title 1", 
   "condition"=>"Cond 2", 
   "description"=>"Descriptive text here", 
   "current_management"=>"curr 3", 
   "condition_trend"=>"Some trend", 
   "trend_notes"=>"Notes on trend here", 
   "vulnerability"=>"Vul 4"}, "commit"=>"Create Monument"}
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "monuments" ("site_name", "visit_date", "parish", "designation_no", "her_no", "site_type", "description", "condition", "current_management", "condition_trend", "trend_notes", "vulnerability") VALUES (           ) RETURNING "id"  [["site_name", "Site 1"], ["visit_date", "2016-04-18"], ["parish", "Parish 1"], ["designation_no", 1010101], ["her_no", 1100110], ["site_type", "Title 1"], ["description", "Descriptive text here"], ["condition", "Cond 2"], ["current_management", "curr 3"], ["condition_trend", "Some trend"], ["trend_notes", "Notes on trend here"], ["vulnerability", "Vul 4"]]
       (1.3ms)  COMMIT
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 78ms

    ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template monuments/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
      * "/Users/user/Development/recorder/app/views"
):
```

New view:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for @monument, url: {action: "create"}, html: {is: "iron-form"} do |f| %>
  <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/monuments">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
      <google-map disable-default-ui zoom="15">
        <google-map-marker></google-map-marker>
      </google-map>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

      <template is="dom-bind" id="scope">
        <section>
          <h3>{{dateFormat(date, 'LL')}}</h3>
          <input type="hidden" name="monument[visit_date]" value="{{dateFormat(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}}" readonly="readonly">
          <paper-button class="btn" on-tap="showDialog" raised>Change Date</paper-button>
          <paper-dialog id="dialog" class="paper-date-picker-dialog" modal on-iron-overlay-closed="dismissDialog">
            <paper-date-picker id="picker"></paper-date-picker>
            <div class="buttons">
              <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
              <paper-button dialog-confirm>OK</paper-button>
            </div>
          </paper-dialog>
        </section>
      </template>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

      <paper-input label="Site name" name="monument[site_name]"></paper-input>
      <paper-input label="Parish" name="monument[parish]"></paper-input>
      <paper-input label="Designation number" name="monument[designation_no]" type="number"></paper-input>
      <paper-input label="HER Number" name="monument[her_no]" type="number"></paper-input>

      <template id="site" is="dom-bind">
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Site type" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
          <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{item}}">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{types}}" as="type">
              <paper-item value="[[type.name]]">[[type.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <input is="iron-input" type="hidden" name="monument[site_type]" value="[[selectedItem.value]]">
      </template>      

      <template id="cond" is="dom-bind">
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Condition" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
          <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{item}}">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{conditions}}" as="condition">
              <paper-item value="[[condition.name]]">[[condition.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <input is="iron-input" type="hidden" name="monument[condition]" value="[[selectedItem.value]]">
      </template>      

      <paper-input id="desc" label="Description" name="monument[description]"></paper-input>

      <template id="curr-mgmt" is="dom-bind">
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Current Management" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
          <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{item}}">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{types}}" as="type">
              <paper-item value="[[type.name]]">[[type.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <input is="iron-input" type="hidden" name="monument[current_management]" value="[[selectedItem.value]]">
      </template> 

      <paper-input label="Condition trend" name="monument[condition_trend]"></paper-input>

      <paper-input label="Trend notes" name="monument[trend_notes]"></paper-input>

      <template id="vulnerability" is="dom-bind">
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Vulnerability" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
          <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{item}}">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{types}}" as="type">
              <paper-item value="[[type.name]]">[[type.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
          </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <input is="iron-input" type="hidden" name="monument[vulnerability]" value="[[selectedItem.value]]">
      </template>   

    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
  $('paper-menu-button').removeAttr('disabled');
});

HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
  var scope = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('#scope');
  var site = document.querySelector('#site'); 
  var condition = document.querySelector('#cond');
  var vulnerability = document.querySelector('#vulnerability');
  var curr_management = document.querySelector('#curr-mgmt');

  scope.dateFormat = function(date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
  };
  scope.dismissDialog = function(event) {
    if (event.detail.confirmed) {
      scope.date = scope.$.picker.date;
    }
  };
  scope.showDialog = function() {
    this.$.dialog.toggle();
  };
  document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    scope.date = new Date();
    scope.showDialog();

    site.set('types',[
      {name:'Title 1'},
      {name:'Title 2'},
      {name:'Title 3'},
      {name:'Title 4'},
      {name:'Title 5'}
    ]);

    condition.set('conditions',[
      {name:'Cond 1'},
      {name:'Cond 2'},
      {name:'Cond 3'},
      {name:'Cond 4'},
      {name:'Cond 5'}
    ]);

    vulnerability.set('types',[
      {name:'Vul 1'},
      {name:'Vul 2'},
      {name:'Vul 3'},
      {name:'Vul 4'},
      {name:'Vul 5'}
    ]);

    curr_management.set('types',[
      {name:'curr 1'},
      {name:'curr 2'},
      {name:'curr 3'},
      {name:'curr 4'},
      {name:'curr 5'}
    ]);

  });
});
```

Controller:

```
class MonumentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @monument = Monument.new 
  end

  def create
    @monument = Monument.new(monument_params)

    if @monument.save
      flash[:success] = "Monument created successfully!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed to create monument entry!"
      render "monuments/new"
    end
  end

  private

    def monument_params
      params.require(:monument).permit(:site_name, :visit_date, 
        :parish, :designation_no, :her_no, :site_type, :description,
        :condition, :current_management, :condition_trend, :trend_notes,
        :vulnerability
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: if monument is successfully created, what do you want your app to do ?

Comment: It's a dumb form really that will be targeted to mobile devices with some additional utilities strapped on I imagine as more requirements emerge. After this I need to write a connector so the data can be exported to various destinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here :

```
if(monument.save)
   flash[:success] = "Monument created successfully!"
   //nothing
else
   flash[:error] = "Failed to create monument entry!"
   render "monuments/new"
end
```

Exactly at the `//nothing` section.

when an action in a controller exits without calling redirect or render rails assumes that you want to render view with the same name as the action name, for example if you have action name `hello` and it exited without calling render or redirect then the view `hello.erb.html` will be rendered, in your case the action name was `create` so It looked for view `create.erb.html`.

I'm assuming you want to redirect to another page if monument was successfully saved, if that's so then call `redirect_to` in the `nothing` section with where you want to redirect.

If you want to do another thing(maybe you want to render json response or etc) then call render with whatever you want your app, if you want to exit without rendering anything then maybe you can write `render nothing:true` or use `head` method to generate HTTP headers without content.

Comment: Such a simple oversight, that solved it. Thank you for your help! I had read about Rails doing that as I mentioned in my question, but I didn't realise the same was true for success and failure... then again why wouldn't it be? Thanks!